# PHP : Getting not matched records from 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Below are the 2 arrays

```
$full = array('ABCD19ed81424931667', 'ABCD0c08b1424947569');   
$filtered = array('ABCD19ed81424931667');
```

I want the records which are not matching in 2 arrays. I have tried
   `array_diff`, `array_diff_assoc` functions it did not work for me.

Comment: 1. Show us your attempts 2. What would be the expected output?

Comment: here is the expected o/p : ABCD0c08b1424947569

Comment: Please also show us your attempt with `array_diff()` (<- array_diff works for me)

Comment: It work find for me using `array_diff($full,$filtered)`

Answer (score 0):

`array_diff` returns the difference in 1 direction. To get the difference in both directions you can do 2 `array_diff` followed by a `array_merge`:

```
$output = array_merge(array_diff($full, $filtered), array_diff($filtered, $full));
```

Answer (score 0):

array_diff — Computes the difference of arrays.

Here array_diff(A,B) and array_diff(B,A) is different.

```
$full = array('ABCD19ed81424931667', 'ABCD0c08b1424947569');   
$filtered = array('ABCD19ed81424931667');
$result = array_merge(array_diff($full, $filtered), array_diff($filtered, $full));
```

array_diff(A,B) returns all elements from A, which are not elements of B (= A without B). so you need to merge output